# MAVEN BUILD FAILURE - Could not resolve dependencies for project XYZ

Tags: java, spring, maven, jersey, pom.xml

I am integrating jersey and spring, for which I have following dependencies, but I am unable to build due to following error:

**My POM file:**

```
<dependencies>

        <!-- Jersey -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
            <version>1.8</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring 3 dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Jersey + Spring -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey.contribs</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-spring</artifactId>
            <version>1.8</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
```

**CONSOLE SCREEN SAYS:**

Failed to execute goal on project SpringRestMavenCalc: **Could not resolve dependencies for project** SpringRestMavenCalc:SpringRestMavenCalc:war:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Failed to collect dependencies for [com.sun.jersey:jersey-server:jar:1.8 (compile), org.springframework:spring-core:jar:3.0.5.RELEASE (compile), org.springframework:spring-context:jar:3.0.5.RELEASE (compile), org.springframework:spring-web:jar:3.0.5.RELEASE (compile), com.sun.jersey.contribs:jersey-spring:jar:1.8 (compile)]: **No versions available for org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:[2.5.2,3) within specified range** -> [Help 1]

Is this versions problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks All for your answers, Learnt lot from your answers.

BUT FOLLOWING CHANGE IN MY POM MADE MY CODE RUN:

Addition of ,

```
<exclusion>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
</exclusion>
```

Comment: As I suggested this may solve your build issues, but watch out for run time problems.

Answer (score 0):

try adding maven dependency for spring-aop with the below:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.2</version>
</dependency>
```

or

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.5.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

i guess one of this should work

Answer (score 0):

No versions available for org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:[2.5.2,3)

Meaning jersey-spring needs **spring-aop 2.5<= version < 3**

**So jersey-spring 1.8 and spring 3.0.5 are incompatible**

I would try the following:

1. Look for newer version of jersey-spring that works with spring 3.0.5. 
   Maybe jersey-spring3 as suggested by [peeskillet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2587435/peeskillet) above.
2. Try my luck with spring 3.0.5 by adding exclusions to jersey-spring dependency. 
   Consult the pom [here](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Ccom.sun.jersey.contribs%7Cjersey-spring%7C1.8%7Cjar) and  including them with version 3.0.5 if needed.